# Pull data out of multiple arrays in csv file for ruby

Tags: ruby

How do I parse through a csv file to check if a value exists in all the array in the csv file? And after just pull the array that contains the value and display it?

```
     require 'csv'

########
## Ask for Serial number
########
serial_number = ask("Product serial number?", true)
serial_number = serial_number.to_s
serial_number = serial_number.upcase
stamp_date= Time.now
old = Time.now.to_i

###################
## CHECK if SN exist in Serial List
###################

CSV.foreach('procedures/Serial.csv') do |row|
    check_serial = row[0]
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? You need to load the CSV, iterate through the rows, search for the value in each row, and display the rows that match. Are you confused about all of these stages? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, `require 'csv'`, then use the [CSV class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html). Better you if can share some code if still stuck.

Comment: You parse a csv with `CSV.parse`. You check if a value exists with methods like `==`, or `Array#include?` (your description is somewhat unclear). You "pull the value that contains it" (??) with methods like `Enumerable#select` or `Enumerable#find`. There is insufficient information in your question for anyone to provide a full code sample, and you haven't shared any attempted solution - so I really don't know what answer you're looking for?

Comment: Not sure what to do after reading through the csv file

Comment: @TomLord I have created this so far

Comment: Can you add csv headers and few rows of a sample data?

Comment: @KTH So what you're actually asking, I think (?) is "How do I find the first row of a CSV file, whose first column matches a given value?". We don't really need to know about code like `ask("Product serial number?", true)`; it's not relevant to the question. But it *would* help to know details like "What is the CSV file?", and "What, exactly, do you want the result to be?" *"Pulling the array and displaying it"* is a vague description. *"Printing the first matching CSV row to STDOUT, i.e. given <this file> it should print <this> to STDOUT"* would be a good description.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this csv file:

```
# starships.csv
serial_number,ship_name,speed
NCC-1701,USS Enterprise,Warp 8
NCC-74656,USS Voyager,Warp 9.975
```

For example, you can lookup at serial number this way:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('starships.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  p row['ship_name'] if row['serial_number'] == "NCC-74656"
  # whatever code
end

#=>"USS Voyager"
```

I do not know the first part of your code, but the second is missing the `end` of the iteration loop.
If you set `headers: true`, the first line is skipped as data and is used to build access keys, allowing you to use `row['ship_name']` instead of `row[0]`, for example.